# Unfortunately project has stopped when tried to integrate Google Maps

Tags: android

I'm trying to integrate Google maps to my app. Received an API key, pasted it, installed Google Play Services, apk files, permissions are also OK. Trying to compile. Code looks similar to that one in tutorial, so as manifest. But I receive "Unfortunately project has stopped".
I've tried many tutorials- nothing helps. That's a code:

cont.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cont_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Contacts"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/n_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="News"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/about_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="About"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/help_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/about_1"
        android:text="Help"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/info_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Info"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/don_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/about_1"
        android:text="Donate"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/zkt_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/help_1"
        android:text="Calculate"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/about_1" />

    <fragment 
        android:id="@+id/fr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Cont.java

```
package com.example.sadaka;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Cont extends FragmentActivity{
    SupportMapFragment fr;

    GoogleMap map;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle conts){
    Button zakat,cont,help,about,n,info,don;
    WebView web;

    super.onCreate(conts);
    setContentView(R.layout.cont);
    zakat=(Button)findViewById(R.id.zkt_1);
    cont=(Button)findViewById(R.id.cont_1);
    help=(Button)findViewById(R.id.help_1);
    about=(Button)findViewById(R.id.about_1);
    n=(Button)findViewById(R.id.n_1);
    info=(Button)findViewById(R.id.info_1);
    don=(Button)findViewById(R.id.don_1);
    web=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.web);
    //web.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/maps/@48.8374914,2.242815,4189m/data=!3m1!1e3");
    fr=(SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fr);
    map=fr.getMap();
    if(map==null){
        finish();
        return;
    }
    init();
    zakat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i1=new Intent(Cont.this,Zakat.class);
            startActivity(i1);
        }
    });
    cont.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i1=new Intent(Cont.this,Cont.class);
            startActivity(i1);
        }
    });
    help.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i1=new Intent(Cont.this,Zakat.class);
            startActivity(i1);
        }
    });
    about.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i1=new Intent(Cont.this,Zakat.class);
            startActivity(i1);
        }
    });
    n.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i1=new Intent(Cont.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i1);
        }
    });
    info.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i1=new Intent(Cont.this,Inf.class);
            startActivity(i1);
        }
    });
    don.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i1=new Intent(Cont.this,Donate.class);
            startActivity(i1);
        }
    });
}
public void init(){

}

public void onClickTest(View view){
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
}
}
```

LogCat:

```
    04-28 01:22:41.928: W/EGL_genymotion(2203): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-28 01:22:47.028: W/EGL_genymotion(2203): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-28 01:22:49.188: W/EGL_genymotion(2203): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-28 01:22:50.924: D/AndroidRuntime(2203): Shutting down VM
04-28 01:22:50.924: W/dalvikvm(2203): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4b87648)
04-28 01:22:50.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2203): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-28 01:22:50.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2203): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sadaka/com.example.sadaka.Cont}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #78: Error inflating class fragment
04-28 01:22:50.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
04-28 01:22:50.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
04-28 01:22:50.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-28 01:22:50.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
04-28 01:22:50.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-28 01:22:50.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-28 01:22:50.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
04-28 01:22:50.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-28 01:22:50.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-28 01:22:50.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
04-28 01:22:50.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-28 01:22:50.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-28 01:22:50.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2203): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #78: Error inflating class fragment
04-28 01:22:50.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
04-28 01:22:50.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
04-28 01:22:50.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
04-28 01:22:50.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
04-28 01:22:50.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
04-28 01:22:50.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
04-28 01:22:50.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
04-28 01:22:50.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at com.example.sadaka.Cont.onCreate(Cont.java:24)
04-28 01:22:50.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
04-28 01:22:50.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-28 01:22:50.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
04-28 01:22:50.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     ... 11 more
04-28 01:22:50.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2203): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: name == null
04-28 01:22:50.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
04-28 01:22:50.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:354)
04-28 01:22:50.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:491)
04-28 01:22:50.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
04-28 01:22:50.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.isSupportFragmentClass(Fragment.java:436)
04-28 01:22:50.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:255)
04-28 01:22:50.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
04-28 01:22:50.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     ... 21 more
04-28 01:22:52.348: I/Process(2203): Sending signal. PID: 2203 SIG: 9
04-28 01:22:53.648: E/cutils-trace(2320): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-28 01:22:53.660: D/TilesManager(2320): Starting TG #0, 0xb85da558
04-28 01:22:53.660: D/TilesManager(2320): new EGLContext from framework: b838d3c8 
04-28 01:22:53.660: D/GLWebViewState(2320): Reinit shader
04-28 01:22:53.768: D/GLWebViewState(2320): Reinit transferQueue
```

Manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sadaka"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <permission 
        android:name="com.example.sadaka.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.sadaka.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAZ4ntXyoqLud8mjORXQPuCUsQ9yTrLUD4"/>
        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
                        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.sadaka.MAINACTIVITY"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
          <activity
            android:name=".Donate"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.sadaka.DONATE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name=".Zakat"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.example.sadaka.ZAKAT"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                </intent-filter>
        </activity>
                 <activity
            android:name=".Inf"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.example.sadaka.INF"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                </intent-filter>
        </activity>
                         <activity
            android:name=".Cont"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.example.sadaka.CONT"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                </intent-filter>
        </activity>       
        <activity
            android:name=".About"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.example.sadaka.ABOUT"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                </intent-filter>
        </activity>       
            </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks for help

Comment: would you like to post your XML code ?

Comment: But I have just posted it first. Or you mean something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fragment XML that you added is not a googlemap fragment its a fragment you just made.

**change this:**

```
<fragment 
    android:id="@+id/fr"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    />
```

**to:**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Comment: Unexpected namespace prefix "xmlns" found for tag fragment on xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android". After I removed this it doesnt go to the Cont page at all

Comment: @user3579259 emove the xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" from the fragment xml

Comment: I removed but now it doesnt jump to the Cont page

Comment: Accepted. But for voting I need 15 reputation points at least